# DCPU-16 Bitwise Shifting

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, dcpu-16

I am trying to learn DCPU.

```
;Set b to 1
SET B,1 ;00001 (1)
SHL B,1 ;00010 (2)
SHL B,1 ;00100 (4)
SHL B,1 ;01000 (8)
SHL B,1 ;10000 (16)
```

All I am doing is shifting to the left one so shouldn't it simply double itself each shift. In my code you can see i have the last shift turning the registry B into 16 but when ran B ends up as 10 why is that.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally displaying the registry value in hexadecimal? :)

Comment: I wish i could answer that all the code is in the original post and the register window says 0x0010 so i am pretty sure that is hex not sure but i am not sure any other way to view it

Answer (score 7):

> the register window says 0x0010...

You're getting the correct answer, you're just viewing it in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Numbers starting with `0x` are the standard way of signifying a hexadecimal number; so the number `0x0010` is is really the number 10<sub>16</sub> *("one-zero in base sixteen")*, which, in decimal, is the number sixteen.

Comment: but then shouldn't it be 0x0016

Comment: @Bevilacqua - Nope, 0x16 would be 0d22 in decimal notation.  0x10 = 0d16 = 0o20 (octal) = 0b10000 (binary); they're all the same number.